# What are the arguments for systemd-coredump

Tags: linux, systemd

What should the input arguments be for

```
/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump
```

?

My core_pattern is `|/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %e`
..but I'm getting

> 0;1;31msystemd-coredump@9-2647-0.service: Failed at step NETWORK spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-coredump: Invalid argument

Now if I change the above to be less than 6 arguments, I get an error saying that there aren't enough arguments and that 6 are expected. But as you can see there are 7 specified above. I have tried removing `%c` as it's not covered in the docs (e.g. https://sysctl-explorer.net/kernel/core_pattern/ ) which brings it down to 6.

I've also tried piping it through a bash script which simply writes the arguments to a file to see what values it's passing in, and including the `%c` above, the values are:

> 2419 0 0 11 1656283414 0 MyApp

The man page for `systemd-coredump` does not say anything about what arguments it's expecting. So what should they be?

(BTW I've tried just setting the core pattern to be `core.%e.%p` (and `/home/root/core.%e.%p`) and I've also set `ulimit -c unlimited` and tried `ulimit -c 1000000`, but the file does not get created).

It's Arago distribution if that's any help...

Answer (score 0):

I still can't post comments which this is, but i really am facing a kind of similar problem on RHEL8, trying to change the core file location. However, on RHEL8.6 running,

```
echo 'core.%p.%e.%t.%h' | tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Does indeed put the core file in the current working directory of the application using the parameters described above for me.